# IIF and LEFT functions

Tags: string, ms-access, iif

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong in this query to get a calculated column?

```
IIf(Left([VIN Number],2)="1F" OR "2F" OR "3F" OR "1L” OR “2L” OR “NM”,”Food”,"Comp")
```

It's giving me error saying *"you may have entered an operand without an operator"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a compound condition like ...

```vb
Something = "a" OR "b"
```

You would have to repeat the `Something =` after `OR` ...

```vb
Something = "a" OR Something = "b"
```

For your query's `IIf()` expression, an `In()` list containing the match values would be more concise ...

```vb
IIf(Left([VIN Number],2) IN ("1F", "2F", "3F", "1L", "2L", "NM"), "Food", "Comp")
```

Beware your code sample includes typesetting quotes (`“` and `”`).  Make sure you use plain quotes (`"`) in your real code.

Answer (score 1):

The OR operator doesn't work how you expect it to.  It requires statements that resolve to TRUE or FALSE on either side of it, so you can't check if something is equal to one of many things like this.

You either need to do:

```
 Iif(Left([VIN Number],2)="1F" OR Left([VIN Number],2)="2F" OR Left([VIN Number],2)="3F"...., "Food", "Comp")
```

or you need to do:

```
Iif(Left([VIN Number],2) In("1F","2F", "3F"....), "Food", "Comp")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help and time. :-)